# making it so alias's work in shell scripts?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, alias, bash-alias

So I don't have python available as a command on my system but I do have python3. So I did `alias python=python3` and I was able to then do `python test.py` insead of just `python3 test.py`.

I then created a new file - test.sh - with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
python test.py
```

After enabling execute permission on that file I do `./test.sh` and I get a `./test.sh: line 2: python: command not found` error.

Per `ps -p $$` I'm running bash, which is the same shell I'm having ./test.sh use.

I also tried to put `alias python=python3` at the bottom of my `~/.bashrc` file but that did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/98782/how-to-run-an-alias-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only interactive shells read ~/.bashrc on startup, and therefore only interactive shells load your alias or function definitions. When the shell is started as a script interpreter, it does not load any external "rc" scripts and the alias is not defined.

In addition, even if aliases *were* defined as part of your script, their expansion is disabled when in "script interpreter" mode. (Bash allows enabling this via 'shopt', but it is better to not do that. Scripts should use functions instead of aliases.)

Instead of using an alias, create an actual 'python' executable somewhere in your $PATH, by symlinking it to the /usr/bin/python3 binary. (~/bin or /usr/local/bin are traditional locations for custom executables.)

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```